# Changing Ivy Cache Location in IntelliJ/Grails

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, ivy

I've tried Googling and searching stackoverflow, but have yet to find a solution too my local development woes.

My User directory on Win7 is synced with a back-up service and I'd like to avoid syncing, but no matter what I've found so far will not change the Ivy cache location.

I've tried the following:

- Setting GRAILS_OPTS env variable
- Setting GRAILS_AGENT_CACHE_DIR env variable
- Modifed my BuildConfig.groovy and entered `System.setProperty "ivy.default.ivy.user.dir", "C:\\.ivy2"`

I only recently started using IntelliJ, so I'm not sure if the IDE is the root cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your BuildConfig.groovy or ~/.grails/settings.groovy

```
grails.dependency.cache.dir = "C:\\.ivy2"
```